# Chrome extensions pageAction.setIcon unreliable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to toggle an icon of my pageAction. This is the code I'm using:

```
var activated = new Boolean();

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
 if(!activated){
        chrome.pageAction.setIcon({tabId: tab.id, path: 'icons/expanded.png'});
        activated = true;
        alert("activated");
    }else{
        chrome.pageAction.setIcon({tabId: tab.id, path: 'icons/expand.png'});
        activated = false;
        alert("not activated");
    }
});
```

Though this works most of the time, sometimes it reports the changed state but doesn't toggle the icon. 
Does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: Did the tab's location change, either by navigation or by use of the `history.pushState/replaceState` APIs? That causes the icon to disappear.

Comment: That is not the issue, the icon doesn't disappear, it just doesn't change to the other image when pressing it sometimes

Comment: Not even if you click twice...? It's very likely that the default `activated` state does not match the corresponding icon path. You have to remember the state per tab instead of globally.

Comment: It does work when I click twice, but then the icon is off-sync with the alerts

Comment: I refer to the second part of my last comment: "You have to remember the state per tab instead of one for all tabs." (Hint: `{}` and `tabId`)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rob W, the problem is now solved. This is the working code:

```
var activated = new Array();

function checkForValidUrl(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
    activated[tabID] = false;
};

chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
 if(!activated[tab.id]){
        chrome.pageAction.setIcon({tabId: tab.id, path: 'icons/expanded.png'});
        activated[tab.id] = true;
        alert("activated");
    }else{
        chrome.pageAction.setIcon({tabId: tab.id, path: 'icons/expand.png'});
        activated[tab.id] = false;
        alert("not activated");
    }
});
```

In stead of using the same state for every open tab, it now stores the state for every individual tab in an array, and uses that.